# Javascript: How to check whether particular TLS version is enabled in browser or not?

Tags: javascript, ssl, browser-detection, browser-security

I would like to check for example whether TLS 1.0/1.1/1.2 is enabled in a browser or not. How can I check that using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check the capabilities of the browser regarding TLS only from within the browser itself. You need at least to make a https connection to some server which then echos the information from the successful handshake back to you.

How this can exactly be done depends on the server, but for apache you get access to the TLS version from the SSL_PROTOCOL environment variable. Of course this only provides common version between client and server, that is if your server can to only TLSv1 but the browser can do TLSv1.2 the common version will only be TLSv1.

Comment: also, your server many not be able to access this information.
Some servers run on HTTP with a middle man proxy (e.g nginx) that applies HTTPS, in such case, you must ensure the proxy is able to set headers such as X-FORWARDED-SOMETHING that your server understands

Answer (score 4):

Just try this

```
<script>
    window.parseTLSinfo = function(data) {
      alert(
        data.tls_version.split(' ')[1] < 1.2
        ? 'So bad! Your browser only supports ' + data.tls_version + '. Please upgrade to a browser with TLS 1.2 support.'
        : 'All OK. Your browser supports ' + data.tls_version + '.'
      );
    };
</script>
<script src="https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check?callback=parseTLSinfo">
```

Comment: I cannot use third party libraries in my project. Is there a way to check without depending on any of the external libraries?

Comment: Also, I tried the above code in IE. Even though TLS 1.2 is enabled in my browser, it is showing message "Your browser supports TLS 1.0, please update to TLS 1.2"

Comment: @Kalyan: That's not a third party library, it's a third party service. Of course you can host something like that yourself if you want.

Comment: @Bergi: How can I do that? Can you please help me here? What they are doing internally in that service implementation to find out TLS version?

Comment: @Kalyan: Looks like they look at the headers, or try different encryptions

Comment: @Kalyan, did you get a chance to implement it internally and host it? Can you please guide me where should I look at for the implementation? I am using Java for webservices. 
thanks in advance.